# Estimate of trace of powers of density matrix

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, density-operator, trace, thermal-field-theory

Given a very generic, lower bounded Hamiltonian, is there a estimate on how $Tr(\rho^{1/k})$ grows as $k>0$ increases? Does this quantity diverge as a function of $N$, the degrees of freedom of the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That trace is nothing but the sum of the non-vanishing $\rho$ eigenvalues to the 1/r power and taking their multiplicities into account. Since those eigenvalues $\lambda$ belong to $(0,1]$, then $\lambda^{1/r}\to 1$ as $r\to +\infty$. In summary $tr(\rho^{1/r})$ tends to the number of non-vanishing eigenvalues of $\rho$ taking multiplicities into account. In particular it can diverge.

Comment: I was writing out a several paragraph long thing while you wrote this and your answer is so much more simple and concise than what I had written. Beautifully done!

Comment: ...I am using my Phone, I must be concise :)

Comment: @CRDrost : Sorry I should have waited a bit longer before accepting the answer.  From next time onwards I shall wait a bit :)

Comment: Actually I omitted some details. For instance, if the eigenvalues are infinitely many one has to use the monotone convergenze theorem...but the substance is that I pointed out.

Comment: @ValterMoretti : But what happens when $r$ is finite ? Is there a way to argue that the trace will be finite ? I should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: It is finite provided the eigenvalues of $\rho$ are not accumulated by $0$. In this case $\rho^{1-e} = \rho \rho^{-e}$ and the second factor is bounded. Since trace class operators form a two-sided ideal in the algebra of bounded operators,  the product is trace class.

Comment: If they are accumulate by $0$ one should study the problem case-by-case...

Comment: I don't fully understand by the term accumalate by 0, but $Tr \rho^{0} = Tr \mathbf{1}$ which basically diverges, so I think $Tr \rho^{-\epsilon}$ shall also diverge. Also given the energies are bounded only from below change in sign will actually give an exponentially growing series. I am wondering if there is a better way of arguing about convergence/divergence ?

Comment: If eigenvalues are accumulate by $0$, the eigenvalues of the positive selfadjoint operator  $\rho^{-\epsilon}$ are accumulate d by $+\infty$. The norm of a positive selfadjoint operator coincides with the sup of its spectrum, so the considererà operator has infinite norm...

Comment: There are cases where the trace is finite for various $r$, though the spectrum admits $0$ as accumulation point. Think of a gas of free bosons in a finite  box. The statistical operator has finite trace for $\beta \in (0,+\infty)$. However this result can be proved by expliciting considering the partition function. (Sorry for various typos, the automatic corrector of my phone understands Italian only)